# Sequelize is returning id null instead of the real id when creating a register

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

When I try to create a new **Usuario** item Sequelize, it should return the item and the id as a result of the insertion, instead of that, equalize is returning null as id, but the insertion is right in my database.

```
const Usuario=mysql_db.define('Usuario', {
id_usuario:{
    primaryKey: true,
    autoIncrement: true,
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11)
},
identificacion:{
    type:DataTypes.STRING
},
nombre: {
    type:DataTypes.STRING
},
password: {
    type:DataTypes.STRING
},
id_role:{
    type:DataTypes.INTEGER
},
activo:{
    type:DataTypes.BOOLEAN
},
fecha_creacion:{
    type:DataTypes.DATE,
    defaultValue:DATE
},
fecha_modificacion:{
    type:DataTypes.DATE
}
},{
tableName:'usuarios'
});
```

**Call of Save method ()**

```
const usuariosPost = async (req, res = response) => {
try {
    let {identificacion,nombre,password} =req.body;
    const usuario= new Usuario({identificacion,nombre,password,activo:'1',id_role:'2'})
    usuario.save();
    res.json({
        msg: 'post API - usuariosPost',
        usuario,
    });

} catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({
        msg:'Comuniquese con el administrador X002'
    })
}
```

}

The primary key is **id_usuario** and it´s declared with the autoIncrement set in true, and this is the result of the **save() method**

[image]

But i´m completely sure that the insert function in my DB is right as shown below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You just didn't wait for the result of `save` call:

```js
await usuario.save();
```

Comment: oh, dude, I feel so dumb, yeah it´s right, now is resolving perfectly! Thank you very much